# Understanding GroupBY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table in SQL Server where personal entries and exits are recorded.
There are multiple hours of entry or exit on the same day. What I need is to recover the first entry and the last exit of the day.

```
Date       hour   Clock
------------------------
01/01/2017 09:00  1
01/01/2017 11:30  2
01/01/2017 17:00  2
02/01/2017  7:59  1
02/01/2017 16:00  1
```

I have this SQL query that works correctly.

```
SELECT  
    d.Date,
    MIN(d.hour) as Entry, 
    MAX(dt.hour) as Exit   
FROM 
    #temp1 AS d
LEFT JOIN 
    #temp1 AS dt ON d.Date = dt.Date
GROUP BY 
    d.Date
ORDER BY
    Date DESC
```

BUT if I add 2 more columns to the query

```
SELECT  
    d.Date,
    d.clock as ClockEntry,       -- Aggregated column to display
    MIN(d.hour) as Entry, 
    dt.clock as ClockExit,       -- Aggregated column to display
    MAX(dt.hour) as Exit
FROM 
    #temp1 AS d
LEFT JOIN 
    #temp1 AS dt ON d.Date = dt.Date
GROUP BY   
    d.Date
ORDER BY
    Date DESC
```

I get this error:

> Column '# temp1.clock' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I just need to group by the field "date", I do not want to add more conditions to the `GROUP BY`.. How could I solve it?

I want this result

```
DATE        ClockEntry     Entry    ClockExit    Exit     
-------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2017     1           09:00        2        17:00
02/01/2017     1            7:59        1        16:00
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want to achieve.

Comment: what kind of data is in the column `clock`?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: So you want the `clock` which recorded the in and out time I presume?

Comment: yes, I want display clock (integer) value

Comment: You have to include all non-aggregated column in the `GROUP BY` statement.  Otherwise it won't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is an easy way to do this - use 2 ranking functions:

1. Partitioned by date, Ordered by the hour ascending
2. Partitioned by date, Ordered by the hour descending

At that point the rows can be joined where they both have a value of 1, and the dates match.

I tend to use a CTE for this:

```
with temp2 (MinId, MaxId, Date, Hour, Clock)
AS
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() Over (partition by date order by hour), 
     ROW_NUMBER() Over (partition by date order by hour desc), 
    *
    from temp1
)
select distinct 
       d1.Date,
       d1.Clock,
       d1.Hour,
       d2.Clock,
       d2.Hour
FROM temp2 d1
LEFT JOIN temp2 d2 
    ON d1.Date = d2.Date  -- dates match
    AND d1.MinId=d2.MaxId -- minId=earliest record MaxId=latest record
WHERE d1.MinId=1
```

Comment: Nice place to implement a CTE

Answer (score -1):

## GROUP BY Method

If you know that only a single value will get out the `clock` column,
just aggregate the values with a `MAX` or `MIN` aggregate function for example like this :

```
SELECT  
d.Date,
MIN(d.clock) as ClockEntry,
MIN(d.hour) as Entry, 
MAX(dt.clock) as ClockExit,
MAX(dt.hour) as Exit

FROM #temp1 AS d
LEFT JOIN #temp1 AS dt 
ON d.Date= dt.Date
GROUP BY   d.Date
order by Date desc
```

Or if you have multiple clock values and want to see them all,
add them to the `GROUP BY` statement :

```
SELECT  
d.Date,
d.clock as ClockEntry,
MIN(d.hour) as Entry, 
dt.clock as ClockExit,
MAX(dt.hour) as Exit

FROM #temp1 AS d
LEFT JOIN #temp1 AS dt 
ON d.Date= dt.Date
GROUP BY   d.Date, d.clock, dt.clock
order by Date desc
```

## ORDER BY Method

Use a [cursor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169(v=sql.110).aspx) or a [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) for each date to get both first entry and last exit.

*First Entry for a given date*

```
SELECT TOP 1 d.date, d.clock as ClockEntry, d.hour as Entry
FROM #temp1 AS d
WHERE d.date = @myDate
ORDER BY d.hour ASC
```

*Last Exit for a given date*

```
SELECT TOP 1 d.date, d.clock as ClockExit, d.hour as Exit
FROM #temp1 AS d
WHERE d.date = @myDate
ORDER BY d.hour DESC
```

### Reference :

[GROUP BY Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)
[AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Your first answer works by serendipity - it is only in the right order because 1 happens to be less than 2. Just using `min(d.hour)` and `max(dt.hour)` is far too simplistic for the real world.

Comment: When I insert "GROUP BY   d.Date, d.clock, dt.clock", I receive duplicated data.  :(

Comment: Works if only one value of the hour column is given for each Date as stated in the answer. Watch this documentation for all aggregate functions available : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: An employee can register on any clocks (they are 5)
What I need is to register the first entry of the day and the last, with their respective clocks

Comment: Use a top 1 with the right ORDER BY, see my edited answer about how to realise it, you will only need to list all dates where people entered or left and use a cursor for it.